# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const' in UI5 (SAP)

Tags: javascript, sapui5, ui5-tooling, ui5-webcomponents

Hi I wanted to make an **API Call** in **Ui5** but everytime it tells me, that it doesnt know whats 'Const'.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'
> The following error occurred while displaying routing target with name 'TargetResult': SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const' -
> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'

my Ui5 call:

```
sap.ui.define([
      "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller", "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
    ], function(Controller, JSONModel) {
      "use strict";

      return Controller.extend("TESTE.TESTE.controller.ResultDevice", {

            onInit: function() {
              var sUrl = "/api/tablets?limit=1000&offset=0";
              const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

              fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(res => (
                  const dataModel = new JSONModel(); dataModel.setData({
                    items: res
                  }); this.getView().setModel(dataModel, "aribadevices")

                )
              },
            },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your curly braces and parenthesis. This code should work, doesn't have syntax errors, and is a little easier to read with each expression being on a new line.

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller", "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
  ], function(Controller, JSONModel) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("TESTE.TESTE.controller.ResultDevice", {

            onInit: function() {
            var sUrl = "/api/tablets?limit=1000&offset=0";
            const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

            fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
                const dataModel = new JSONModel(); 
                dataModel.setData({
                    items: res
                }); 
                this.getView().setModel(dataModel, "aribadevices");
            })
        }
    })
});
```